# TensorFlow SavedModel export fails with AttributeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm following the tutorial exactly as it is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification_with_hub

Finally, if I want to export the trained model from this tutorial using `model.save()` I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-768eb5acd4e8> in <module>()
      3 
      4 export_path = "/tmp/saved_models/{}".format(int(t))
----> 5 model.save(export_path, save_format='tf')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
    984     """
    985     saving.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
--> 986                       signatures, options)
    987 
    988   def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=True, save_format=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options)
    113   else:
    114     saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,
--> 115                           signatures, options)
    116 
    117 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py in save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, signatures, options)
     72   # default learning phase placeholder.
     73   with K.learning_phase_scope(0):
---> 74     save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
     75 
     76   if not include_optimizer:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py in save(obj, export_dir, signatures, options)
    905   # Note we run this twice since, while constructing the view the first time
    906   # there can be side effects of creating variables.
--> 907   _ = _SaveableView(checkpoint_graph_view)
    908   saveable_view = _SaveableView(checkpoint_graph_view)
    909 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py in __init__(self, checkpoint_view)
    189           concrete_functions = [function]
    190         for concrete_function in concrete_functions:
--> 191           if concrete_function.name not in seen_function_names:
    192             seen_function_names.add(concrete_function.name)
    193             self.concrete_functions.append(concrete_function)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

What's going on? Shouldn't it be possible to simply export this model to the `SavedModel` format?

Comment: try to not use `save_format='tf'` as it is experimental still as per of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, tried this but still the same error appears. I wonder if it has to do with Hub layer in the Keras model?

Comment: Something doesn't work around functions as it try to use `concrete_function.name` which doesn't exist i.e. `NoneType`.
Please, try to post it on Tensorflow or Keras github Issues.